# Mobile menu will not close when Bootstrap JS is below jQuery JS issue

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently hitting a strange roadblock with Boostrap's mobile nav bar where if I place the Bootstrap JS script below the jQuery JS script (where it should be), the mobile menu will open, but will not close. However, if I flip the order of the scripts, the mobile menu works flawlessly! I read about how this might be where I may have a duplicate JS somewhere, but I cannot find a duplicate.

Script order:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

Header (where the navbar is):

```
<header>
        <div class="heading container-fluid">
            <div class="btn-group searchbar-top">
                <input id="searchinput" type="search" placeholder="Search for a song" class="form-control">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search-button-desktop"></i>
            </div>
            <a class="heading-image" href=""><img id="my-heading" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/logo_header.png" alt="UNCVRD"></a>
            <ul class="signup-login-buttons">

              <?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
                <li>
                  <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">LOGOUT</a>
                </li>
              <?php } else { ?>
                <!-- <a class="login_button" id="show_login" href="">Login</a> -->
                <li><a id="desktop-bar-signup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalsignup" href="#">SIGN UP</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-login" href="#">LOG IN</a></li>
              <?php } ?>


            </ul>

        </div>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="btn-group searchbar-top">
                <input id="searchinput" type="search" placeholder="Search for a song" class="form-control">
                <span id="searchclear" class="icon ion-android-close"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="pull-left navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search-button"></i>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/logo_header.png" alt="UNCVRD"></a>
                    <a class="mobile-signup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalsignup" href="#">Sign Up</a>
                </div>

                                <?php
                                    wp_nav_menu(array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                        'container' => 'nav',
                                        'container_class' => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
                                        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                                        'container_id' => 'myNavbar'
                                    ));
                                ?>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: you dont need to include jquery libraray link in footer. because wordpress is already included in top of the page.
you can view by view page source on browsr

Comment: does removing your `jquery.min.js` fix the issue?

Comment: @RajshekarReddy removing the jquery file fixes the menu issue but now none of my main.js scripts work. console says "$ not a function"

Comment: @JordanLewallen looks like its CSS issue.. because if you are getting `$ not defined` then even the `bootstrap.js` had to break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to include jquery libraray link in footer. because wordpress is already included in top of the page. you can view by view page source on browser.

for this
 removing the jquery file fixes the menu issue but now none of my main.js scripts work. console says "$ not a function"

you can use

`(function($){`

or you can use `jQuery` instead of `$`